# Error 'swiper-slide' is not a known element after migrating from ion-slides

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js, ionic5

I updated my Angular Ionic 5 application and trying to migrate from `ion-slides` to `Slides`. I am following the official [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/slides).

- I installed swiper `npm install swiper@6`
- Did import in the `scss` file `@import '~swiper/swiper';`
- Did import the SwiperModule in `app.module.ts` and my
  `page.module.ts`

> ```
> import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [SwiperModule],
> })
> export class AppModule {}
> ```

The HTML page is able to recognize `swiper` after I imported the `SwiperModule` in  my `page.module.ts` but it's not able to recognize `swiper-slide` and showing error `'swiper-slide' is not a known element`

```
<swiper>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
</swiper>
```

Comment: use it this way in HTML: 

`<swiper
      [slidesPerView]="3"
      [spaceBetween]="50"
      (swiper)="onSwiper($event)"
      (slideChange)="onSlideChange()"
    >
      <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>
      <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 2</ng-template>
      <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 3</ng-template>
    </swiper>`

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib, with this code the error is gone and the slides are visible but it's not at all working like `ion-slides`. All the slide contents are coming vertically in the same view. There is no styling applied. I have tried changing the config option of the slider but it's the same. As per the ionic document I have imported `@import '~swiper/swiper';` in the scss class.

Comment: check swiper documentation and Ignore ionic docs: https://swiperjs.com/angular

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib, thank you for your inputs. I got it working with swiper documentation. I would keep this open as it should work with the Ionic components

Answer (score 1):

After adding to AppModule, Please add SwiperModule to Page Level Module also where component is registered.

Answer (score -1):

On the ionic documentation:

```
<ion-content>
  <swiper>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 2</ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 3</ng-template>
  </swiper>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case.
Open component.module.ts,
Adding by following:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    **ComponentName**
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    **SwiperModule,**
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
          path: '',
          component: **ComponentName**,
          children: [],
      },
    ]),
  ]
})
```

Good luck!